# Segmentation fault in MPI_Test() when using singleton/wrapper classes

Tags: c++, mpi

During my work writing a C++ wrapper for MPI I ran into a segmentation fault in `MPI_Test()`, the reason of which I can't figure out.

The following code is a minimal crashing example, to be compiled and run with `mpic++ -std=c++11 -g -o test test.cpp && ./test`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>
#include <mpi.h>

class Environment {
public:
    static Environment &getInstance() {
        static Environment instance;
        return instance;
    }

    static bool initialized() {
        int ini;
        MPI_Initialized(&ini);
        return ini != 0;
    }

    static bool finalized() {
        int fin;
        MPI_Finalized(&fin);
        return fin != 0;
    }

private:
    Environment() {
        if(!initialized()) {
            MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
            _initialized = true;
        }
    }

    ~Environment() {
        if(!_initialized)
            return;
        if(finalized())
            return;
        MPI_Finalize();
    }

    bool _initialized{false};

public:
    Environment(Environment const &) = delete;
    void operator=(Environment const &)  = delete;
};

class Status {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<MPI_Status> _mpi_status;
    MPI_Datatype _mpi_type;
};

class Request { 
private:
    std::shared_ptr<MPI_Request> _request;
    int _flag;
    Status _status;
};

int main() {
    auto &m = Environment::getInstance();

    MPI_Request r;
    MPI_Status s;
    int a;
    MPI_Test(&r, &a, &s);

    Request r2;
    printf("b\n");
}
```

Basically, the `Environment` class is a singleton wrapper around `MPI_Init` and `MPI_Finalize`. When the program exits, MPI will be finalized and the first time the class is instantiated, `MPI_Init` is called. Then I do some MPI stuff in the `main()` function, involving some other simple wrapper objects.

The code above crashes (on my machine, OpenMPI & Linux). However, it works when I

- comment any of the private members of `Request` or `Status` (even `int _flag;`)
- comment the last line, `printf("b\n");`
- Replace `auto &m = Environment::getInstance();` with `MPI_Init()`.

There doesn't seem to be a connection between these points and I have no clue where to look for the segmentation fault.

The stack trace is:

```
[pc13090:05978] *** Process received signal ***
[pc13090:05978] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[pc13090:05978] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[pc13090:05978] Failing at address: 0x61
[pc13090:05978] [ 0] /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x11dd0)[0x7fa9cf818dd0]
[pc13090:05978] [ 1] /usr/lib/openmpi/libmpi.so.40(ompi_request_default_test+0x16)[0x7fa9d0357326]
[pc13090:05978] [ 2] /usr/lib/openmpi/libmpi.so.40(MPI_Test+0x31)[0x7fa9d03970b1]
[pc13090:05978] [ 3] ./test(+0xb7ae)[0x55713d1aa7ae]
[pc13090:05978] [ 4] /usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xea)[0x7fa9cf470f4a]
[pc13090:05978] [ 5] ./test(+0xb5ea)[0x55713d1aa5ea]
[pc13090:05978] *** End of error message ***
-------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node pc13090 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Your `Environment` wrapper smells of thread-unsafeness.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue here, but could you suggest how to improve it anyway? Thanks!

Comment: Consider what happens if two or more threads construct an `Environment` object at the same time.  That would be a race condition.  I only mentioned threading issues due to this message `usr/lib/libpthread.so.`.  It may be a red herring, I don't know -- others could comment.

Comment: You're right. I guess this could be solved using a simple mutex?

Comment: For starters yes, a mutex can be used.

Comment: `r` is uninitialized, so if you pass it to `MPI_Test()`, all bets are off.

Comment: I was wondering about that, too, but then sometimes it works... Is there no way I can create an "empty" request, that returns false when used in `MPI_Test()`?

Comment: It never works, sometimes you are lucky and you have the illusion it worked. There is `MPI_REQUEST_NULL`, but I am not sure this is a valid parameter for `MPI_Test()` though.